# How to render textarea input with new line

Tags: html, google-app-engine, newline

I have a textarea:

```
<textarea type="text" name="note" placeholder = "note" value="{{note}}"cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
```

This line gets the value of the textarea input:

```
note = self.request.get('note')
```

I first tried committing just this to the database, but the rendered note doesn't have the original line breaks. I then tried inserting these lines after the above code

```
note = note.replace('\n', '<br>')
```

and

```
note = note.replace('\n', '&#13;&#10;')
```

and

```
note = note.replace('\n', '\r\n')
```

But none of them worked. How can I preserve the original new lines in the rendered input?

Comment: What original line breaks? Are you referring to line breaks that are caused by a user by pressing Enter, or line breaks added by a browser *in display* to make the text lines fit into a specific number of columns (i.e., automatic wrapping, which by defaut is not included in the element content)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The bug was in the html that rendered the text. I had

```
{{item.note}}
```

in a for loop, which I changed to

```
{{item.note | safe}}
```

I'm also using

```
note = note.replace('\n', '<br>')
```

for the python.